# Stopping GPS after Exit is pressed

Tags: android

I have an application which tracks the location with the help of GPS. Now when I enter back the Tracking is still going on. This continues even when I press the exit button. I have used finish() , but GPS doesn't stop when I press exit button.

Comment: Unregister the LocationListener.

Comment: did you mean this  "case exit : mylocover.disableMyLocation(); 
        locman1.removeUpdates(this);"?? here i have given only for exit button.But  the GPS is stoped for both exit and back button,which i need only for exit

Comment: Nope. The one that @AlexisCartier mentioned in his answer.

Comment: If you have a `MapView`, do you have a `MyLocationOverlay`?

Answer (score 1):

To interrupt GPS :

```
myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
```

Doing nothing on the key back pressed event:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            myActivity.finish();
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
            myActivity.finish();
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);;
    }
```

Comment: Sir i have added this coding for exit button the GPS is stopping but the same happens even if i press BACK ???what should i do for having my GPS on even after pressing BACK

Comment: here in the code , are you asking us to remove the updates after BACK is pressed... Or after EXIT .."if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)"

Comment: So if I understood well, you want your GPS working even if you press the back button ?

Comment: Yes ur rite.. GPS working only after BACK and not after EXIT.

Comment: Then just override the key back event and do nothing. I edited

Comment: Ok sir this worked for back.. But what should i do in the EXIT button because i have added this finish() even in EXIT.. is that right ??

Comment: What do you mean by EXIT Button? Is it the HOME Button? If its that I edited.

Comment: Then set an OnClickListener on it, and remove the locationListener when he's pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. I will try 2 implement and get back if i have any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Your activity needs to implement the `onPause` method, which is triggered when the user leaves it. Inside it, you can stop the GPS by calling:

```
myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have a `MyLocationOverlay` in your code, this start a `SensorThread` on its own.  You will have to disable that too.

```
protected void onPause() {
    //....your code
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
}
```

and it will shut that down too.